# Word to refer to a mother/father who has daughters vs. having sons

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was wondering if there is an English word or short phrase referring to a mother/father of sons as opposed to a mother/father of daughters (and vice versa).

The situation could be that someone who has a daughter has different concerns, let's say, in parenting than someone who has a son would have.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: I can think of nothing briefer than the phrase "mother of three girls" or other permutations.

Comment: We would need six more words for a parent: mother/father of girls/both/boys.

Comment: Some years ago I was watching a movie, I can't remember its name, where an English-speaker visiting a foreign country did not understand something that had been said in the local language about a man who had just left the room; all the other men in the room chuckled when they heard it. The English speaker asked what the man had been called and someone explained to him that he had been called a word that meant *father-of-daughters*.  We don't have any such word in English.

Comment: Is this a concept with a word/phrase in your native language?

Comment: Yes, it is a common expression made up of two words (one of which is "mother" or "father", and the other is an adjective specifying whether they have boys or girls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty certain the answer is "no, there is no such word or dedicated short phrase in English" (by "dedicated short phrase" I mean a phrase that's always used for this specific meaning, as opposed to every person making a sentence anew when they talk about the concept).

That's pretty hard to prove unfortunately, and maybe someone will answer with an example. But here is an article, referring to the specific concept, I found while googling "parent only boys" and "parent only girls":

https://www.forbes.com/sites/kateashford/2017/09/30/boys/#53e59eca2724

This article refers to a study on parents who have only girls and only boys and how they spend for college. If the word existed and was common enough you'd expect an article and study like this to use it. But they don't; they talk about "parents of all boys" and "parents of all girls" in the article and "parents of only boys" in the title, suggesting none of those are dedicated phrases either.

EDIT: I just want to react to the recent answer by Mass, as it appears to contradict this one. I'm not going to look it up right now so I recommend someone do so, but I *am* also familiar with the usage they mention so I endorse their answer, however I also agree with them about being fairly recent slang which might not be familiar to readers of all backgrounds and has specific connotations (such as being a very casual register). Offhand I think I've run into this expression in forums, parenting blogs, maybe trend articles about parenting, and I feel it's used in a kind of light-hearted self-descriptor more than a serious, neutral category the way it would be if it were fully part of the language ?

I'm also slightly unclear on whether "Girl Dad" or "Boy Mom" is supposed to refer to a parent that has at least one child of the gender, or has several children exclusively of that gender, if that's a distinction that mattered to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a slang term that has become really common.  *Girl Dad* or *Boy Dad* etc.

In an article by [The Standard](https://www.standardmedia.co.ke/evewoman/parenting/article/2001459548/what-it-means-being-a-girl-dad#:%7E:text=It%20is%20used%20to%20refer,we%20are%20not%20quite%20there.%E2%80%9D), it appears that “**girl dad**” was coined sometime in 2020

> The phrase ‘girl dad’ was popularised after the tragic passing away of NBA star Kobe Bryant in a 2020 helicopter crash. The athlete died alongside his 13-year-old daughter Gianna. **It is used to refer to dads who have daughters** and is often used to capture the love between fathers and their daughters.

Comment: Hi Mass, it would improve your answer if you could tell us where you've heard this being used, and how frequent you think its usage is.

Comment: Hi, I just ran across this post and I just want add to Joachim's comment - I'm really excited you came up with this usage I hadn't thought about at all when I wrote my comment and I totally agree with you, it does seem to be exactly what the questioner was asking about ! So it would be really great if you (or anyone reading this tbh but four years in that's gonna be me and you) went into more detail on where those terms are used, the details of what they mean, links to examples etc.